# What do I need to change the look of Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, themes, customization, 17.10

I found gnome-look.org, but I'm a bit confused about what I need to download in order to theme Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome version).

[image]

I'm not sure on the difference between GTK2, GTK3, GDM, Gnome Shell, etc.

Comment: Which part are you trying to modify?

Comment: Er.. everything? Windows, window titlebars, colors, etc.

Comment: Those are usually controlled by GTK+ themes, nowadays mostly  GTK+ 3. But some older applications which haven't migrated to GTK+3 may still use GTK+2. Also some qt based apps use qt toolkit instead of GTK+.

Comment: Ok, so I take it Ubuntu 17.10 would use GTK3. What does Gnome Shell themes refer to then? (I figured out GDM = greeter)

Comment: GNOME Shell theme controls top bar style, activities overview/show applications style etc. Your question is too broad as it stands. I would suggest you to start playing around with stuffs. That will certainly help you to get a clear view.

Comment: @pomsky Ok. I'll remove this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may keep it and see if someone comes with a concrete answer. Or maybe you should convert into a community wiki.